# Can I replace a non-functioning CD drive using a working one from another PlayStation?

Tags: ps1

I have a PlayStation with a parallel port that has a disc drive that won't spin, and a second PlayStation console without a parallel port that works just fine.

Is there a way to combine the two systems so I can use the port or take the functional disc drive and put it into the one with the port?

Comment: What's the reason for needing to keep the parallel port? The only thing I can think of that used it was GameShark.

Comment: For a game shark. We took the disc drives out but they seem to be slightlu different models and don't quite fit right.

Comment: Well, is it possible to put the drive in? have you tried plugging it in?

Comment: The PSX went through quite a few hardware iterations, I'd imagine that it might be possible, but to be able to answer the question, we need to know the specific model numbers of both systems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to check the CD drive part number first.

Take out the CD drive assembly and flip it over. There is a square label on the underside with text in the format "KSM-440xxx". If the "xxx" is the same on both drives you can exchange them directly. For example if both are KSM-440ACM you can exchange them.

If they are different, then I can tell from experience that you replacing a KSM-440ACM with a KSM-440BAM drive works, but the latter is slightly larger. You'll have to use snippers to remove some plastic around the perimeter of the plastic case that sits over the drive. It's pretty easy to do.

I would imagine the opposite is true (putting a KSM-440ACM in a KSM-440BAM console), but I haven't tried that.